# Parsing Multiple XML Files with Custom tags

Tags: xml, parsing, go

I have to parse many XML documents, I already know the logic to parse the files, but the issue is, the tag for each xml file is different.

This is what I have so far

```
type Data struct {
     Rows []Info `xml:"domain-google.com"` // <- This is custom and needs to change (e.g. the next xml doc tag will be `xml:"domain-facebook.com"`
}

type Info struct {
     Domain string `xml:"domain"`
 }
```

// example logic for parsing xml

```
    xmlFile, err := http.Get("somefiles.xml")
    if err != nil { fmt.Println(err) }
    var data Data
    if err = xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile.Body).Decode(&data); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    for _, rows := range data.Rows {
        fmt.Println(rows.Domain)
    }
```

example xml documents

```
<response>
   <!-- This tag is what is custom every time -->
   <domain-google.com>
      <domain>google.com</domain>
   </domain-google.com>
</response>

<response>
   <!-- This tag is what is custom every time -->
   <domain-facebook.com>
      <domain>facebook.com</domain>
   </domain-facebook.com>
</response>
```

Any idea how to tackle this issue?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Your example is not very clear, what wrapping the responses tags?

Comment: Nothing wraps the response tags. That example was the whole XML doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As XML goes, this is pretty bad; tag names should not be used for data, only tag bodies and attribute values should hold data. But, all is not lost! Per [the documentation on `encoding/xml`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal), you can use the `,any` tag to map a field that should contain "a sub-element that hasn't matched any of the above rules". You can use this as a sort of wildcard, to match any child element not otherwise mapped - in your case, a child element whose tag name you don't know at compile time:

```
type Data struct {
    Rows []Info `xml:",any"`
}
```

Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/lo6bJBRvgV

Comment: Thank you for that, was wondering if there was a wildcard for that. Completely agree with you on that, no data is given for the tag name. on the API I'm using, the tag name is dynamic, bad on their part to be honest, but couldn't do anything about it. All the data is held in the tag body luckily. Thanks for the answer!